# Update HTML text with video title using YouTube Embed API

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Currently struggling to figure out how to update a string of text with the YouTube title when a new video is played using the YouTube Embed API.

Here is the relevant HTML segment I want to update:

```
<div id="bottom-song-title" class="song-name">No song is playing</div>
```

Here is my current API code (majority of this code is for the pause play and the progress bar), I think this is the function I'd want to use correct?:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        console.log("END!");
        clearTimeout(timeout_setter);
        document.getElementById("progress-bar-bottom").style.cssText = "transition: none;";
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("PLAYING");
        loopy();
        document.getElementById("progress-bar-bottom").style.cssText = "transition: all 1s linear 0s;";
    } else {
        console.log(event.data);
    }

    var state = player.getPlayerState();
    if (state == 1) {
        jQuery('#media-toggle').click(function (event) {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('#media-toggle').click(function (event) {
            player.playVideo();
        });
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        jQuery('#media-toggle-bottom').click(function (event) {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('#media-toggle-bottom').click(function (event) {
            player.playVideo();
        });
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        jQuery('.media-circle').click(function (event) {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.media-circle').click(function (event) {
            player.playVideo();
        });
    }
}
```

I tried using an innerHTML technique but I couldn't get the string to update..any thoughts?

Current site for you to look at: https://www.uncvrd.co

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, this is how I accomplished this:

`document.getElementById("bottom-song-title").textContent = event.target.getVideoData().title;`

Hope this helps someone!